# How can I build plotly heatmap faster?

Tags: python, numpy, plotly, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap plot with slider using python plotly

Here is my sample code.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly as py
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import time

# make test histogram. np.array
histogram_meter = np.random.randint(0, 500,(50,100))

# get figures
fig = go.Figure()

# add sliders
cnt_max = int(histogram_meter.max())           

if(len(tmp_histogram) != 0):
    avg = histogram_meter[histogram_meter != 0].mean()
    std = histogram_meter[histogram_meter != 0].std()
else:
    avg = 0
    std = 0
step_max  = int(avg + 2 *std)  # 2-sigma                      
step_list = list(range(0, step_max))
time_check = time.time()
for step in step_list:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Heatmap(
            visible=False,
            z=histogram_meter,
            zsmooth='fast',
            connectgaps=True,
            colorscale=[[0, 'rgba(0, 0, 255,0)'],
                        [0.1, 'rgba(0, 0, 255,1)'],
                        [1.0, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)']],
            zmin=0,
            zmax=step
        )
    )

print("time check for drawing heatmap = ", time.time()-time_check)
time_check = time.time()
fig.data[step_max-1].visible = True

time_check = time.time()
steps = []
for i in range(step_max):  # range(len(fig.data)):
    # time_check2 = time.time()
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[
            {"visible": [False]*len(fig.data)},
            {"title": "Threshold switched to : " + str(i)}],  # layout attribute
        label=" {}".format(i)
    )
    # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True
    steps.append(step)
    # print("time check add 1-step to slider = ", time.time()-time_check2)

print("time check for drawing slider = ", time.time()-time_check)
time_check = time.time()

sliders = [dict(
    active=step_max-1,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Threshold: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]
fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders)
print("time check for update_layout(slider) = ", time.time()-time_check)
time_check = time.time()

# configure color bar
colorbar = dict(
    title="count",
    thicknessmode="pixels", thickness=50,
    lenmode="pixels", len=400,
    yanchor="top", y=1,
    ticks="outside", ticksuffix="count",
    dtick=5
)
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar=colorbar)
fig.update_layout(font_size=20)
print("time check for update_layout(color_bar) = ", time.time()-time_check)
time_check = time.time()
fig.show()

print("end")
```

when number of sample data is 100,

```
time check for drawing heatmap =  0.15591144561767578
time check for drawing slider =  0.0
time check for update_layout =  0.0879526138305664
time check for update_layout(color_bar) =  0.1019136905670166
```

and plot is generated in a second.

when number of sample data is 500,

```
time check for drawing heatmap =  0.4447438716888428
time check for drawing slider =  0.007018089294433594
time check for update_layout(slider) =  0.47070741653442383
time check for update_layout(color_bar) =  0.08794975280761719
```

In this case, it takes too long for the heatplot to be drawn. (Exactly, the heatmap plot appears to be still loading. )

I think, there are some problem in my code.
Is there any way to improve my code?

Can you help me??